# Incorect value of incremented value inside lambda and new Thread

Tags: java, synchronization, atomicinteger

I create 10 parallel network requests.
**And I need to understand when all of them was  finished.**

I try to do this via *AtomicInteger* and *synchronized* block. But it not help.

Size of hostInfoList = 10.

Here snippet:

```
    AtomicInteger countOfResponse = new AtomicInteger(0);
    LOGGER.info("myMethod: hostInfoList_size  = {}", hostInfoList.size());
    for (HostInfo hostInfo : hostInfoList) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails();
            XML response = null;
            try {
                LOGGER.info("");
                response = execute_network_request(); // run network request
                LOGGER.info("myMethod: before_inc_count = {}", countOfResponse.get());
                synchronized (this) {
                    countOfResponse.incrementAndGet();
                }
                LOGGER.info("myMethod:after_inc_count = {}", countOfResponse.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorDetails.setDetails(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                LOGGER.info("myMethod: finally")
                if (countOfResponse.get() ==  hostInfoList.size()) {
                   LOGGER.info("myMethod: finished all requests");
                 } 
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

And here log:

```
2024-02-15 13:28:08.558 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-275] myMethod: before_inc_count = 0
2024-02-15 13:28:08.558 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-272] myMethod: before_inc_count = 0
2024-02-15 13:28:08.558 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-275] myMethod: after_inc_count = 2
2024-02-15 13:28:08.558 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-272] myMethod: after_inc_count = 2
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-275] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-272] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-274] myMethod: before_inc_count = 2
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-274] myMethod:after_inc_count = 3
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-271] myMethod: before_inc_count = 3
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-274] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-273] myMethod: before_inc_count = 3
2024-02-15 13:28:08.559 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-271] myMethod:after_inc_count = 4
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-273] myMethod:after_inc_count = 5
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-271] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-273] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-276] myMethod: before_inc_count = 5
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-276] myMethod:after_inc_count = 6
2024-02-15 13:28:08.560 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-276] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-277] myMethod: before_inc_count = 6
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-277] myMethod:after_inc_count = 7
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-277] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-278] myMethod: before_inc_count = 7
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-278] myMethod:after_inc_count = 8
2024-02-15 13:28:08.562 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-278] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.563 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-279] myMethod: before_inc_count = 8
2024-02-15 13:28:08.563 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-279] myMethod:after_inc_count = 9
2024-02-15 13:28:08.563 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-279] myMethod: finally
2024-02-15 13:28:08.564 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-280] myMethod: before_inc_count = 9
2024-02-15 13:28:08.564 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-280] myMethod:after_inc_count = 10
2024-02-15 13:28:08.564 INFO  [MyClass:Thread-280] myMethod: finally
```

As you can see *before_inc_count* = **0** and then *after_inc_count* =   **2**.

But where is the *after_inc_count* = **1** ?

Comment: By the way, you are essentially reinventing [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` is only atomic *per method call*. If you make multiple method calls to it, each of those is atomic (and guarantees visibility), but there is no guarantee that the calls to the methods aren't interleaved between threads.

```
LOGGER.info("myMethod: before_inc_count = {}", countOfResponse.get());
synchronized (this) {
  countOfResponse.incrementAndGet();
}
LOGGER.info("myMethod:after_inc_count = {}", countOfResponse.get());
```

You've got 3 method calls here. They will execute in program order in a single thread, but there is no guaranteed order between threads.

This means that you could get execution like this:

```
Thread 1          Thread 2

get()                                   -> value is 0
                  get()                 -> value is 0
incrementAndGet()                       -> value is 1, but you don't print it
                  incrementAndGet()     -> value is 2, but you don't print it
get()                                   -> value is 2
                  get()                 -> value is 2
```

To do this "atomically", you don't need the synchronized block at all:

```
int valueBefore;
LOGGER.info("myMethod: before_inc_count = {}", valueBefore = countOfResponse.getAndIncrement());
LOGGER.info("myMethod:after_inc_count = {}", valueBefore + 1);
```

(There isn't really any point in logging the after value, because you now know it's one more than what it was before)

Note, however, that the calls to `LOGGER.info` are not atomic, so might still interleave between threads, so the messages may not display in ascending order.

Moreover, even a single invocation of `LOGGER.info` involves invoking the `getAndIncrement` method, so you might get interleaving between threads even with just the first log message.

You could avoid that by wrapping the log lines in a synchronized block; but honestly, accessing an `AtomicInteger` within a synchronized block is a bit of an indicator of a deeper issue.